# Kotlin algorithm to reverse a given string

Tags: kotlin

I'm creating an algorithm in Kotlin that should reverse a given string and output it, so, for example, the string would be "**Hello World!** and the output would be "**olleH !dlroW**. I know there's a function that does this already but I'm practising with loops and if statements so I'm doing it myself.

So far, I've got most of a working solution, the only problem with the code I have in that it only works with odd length strings, because of a while loop. I've put what I have in this post.

I'm stuck on what to change to make this program work with strings that are of an even length, currently with those strings, the program falls into an infinite loop because the condition is never met.

The exclusion part of the program will jump over characters that are included in the exclusion string, I've already tested this and it works fine, provided the string minus the skipped character is not of even length.

```
fun main() {
    val userInput = ""
    val exclusion = ""
    
    val wordsInString = userInput.split(" ")
    var wordsSize = wordsInString.size
    var wordPointer = 0

    while (wordPointer < wordsSize) {
        var currentWord = wordsInString[wordPointer]
        var charArray = currentWord.toCharArray()
    
        var charPointerOne = 0
        var charPointerTwo = currentWord.length - 1
 
        while (charPointerOne != charPointerTwo) {
            if (exclusion.contains(charArray[charPointerOne])) {
                charPointerOne++
            } else if (exclusion.contains(charArray[charPointerTwo])) {
                    charPointerTwo--
                } else {
                    var charToSwtichOne = charArray[charPointerOne]
                    var charToSwitchTwo = charArray[charPointerTwo]
                    charArray[charPointerOne] = charToSwitchTwo
                    charArray[charPointerTwo] = charToSwtichOne
                    charPointerOne++
                    charPointerTwo--
                }
        } 
    wordPointer++
    var outputString = String(charArray)
    print(outputString + " ")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the loop control condition to use `<` instead of `!=`. because in case of even length strings they simply never meet and jump over. for example if you had a `String` of length two, then on first iteration `charPointerOne` will have value `0` and `charPointerTwo` will have value `1`, and on the next iteration `charPointerOne` will be incremented to `1` and `charPointerTwo` will be decremented to `0` and these values still satisfy the loop control hence the loop continues. So to fix this change your code as

```
while (charPointerOne < charPointerTwo)
```